# How can we scale and rotate a water mark and overlay on video using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

How can we scale and rotate a water mark and overlay on video using FFmpeg

I have been able to rotate the watermark but not been able to scale it simultaneously

```
String[] complexCommand2 = {"-y", "-i", videoFilePath, "-i", imagepath, "-filter_complex","[1:v]  rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10",  "-codec:a","copy", outputFilePath};
```

This is the command I have used for rotating , how can we scale and rotate the watermark and overlay on video

Answer (score 0):

Insert a scale filter after the rotate, e.g.

`[1:v]rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih),scale=300:-1[rotate];`

Comment: Could you expand on why it works this way?